# updated android-studio to 3.1.3;how to run application on phone in new version;Please select android sdk

Tags: android-studio

under general tab there is module.which is selected to app.under Installation options there is Deploy which is selected to default APK. There is Install flags which is empty. there is Launch options. Under that Launch is selected to default activity.Then there is Launch flags which is empty.Then there is deployment target options which is selected to Target:USB device.

How do I run my app on mobile phone
earlier the phone icon was displayed on  studio and I had to click the icon. Now in 3.1.3 it is different

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your android phone is connected to the laptop using USB Cable.
Also, make sure usb debugging is on.
Then, when you run the app module, it will run the adb and show you the list of virtual devices you created and the usb connected mobile phone.
Select the mobile phone from the list of options and press ok.
Gradle build will run and then it will install the apk on that connected mobile phone.
If it doesnt install, check the errors under the run console.

Answer (score 0):

I clicked sync gradle button, it did some downloads. Now it is ok